# Number of extremal $\{0,1\}$ matrices having permanent $1$ property

Tags: co.combinatorics, enumerative-combinatorics, perfect-matchings, bipartite-graphs, permanent

1. Is there a function which describes the number of $\{0,1\}^{n\times n}\cap\mathbb Z^{n\times n}$ matrices having permanent $1$?

I think it might be $\mathsf{poly}(n!)$ bounded.

2. Is there a function which describes the number of $\{0,1\}^{n\times n}\cap\mathbb Z^{n\times n}$ matrices having permanent $0$ for which there is a single matrix in $\{0,1\}^{n\times n}\cap\mathbb Z^{n\times n}$ having a single $1$ which if added provides a $0/1$ matrix having permanent $1$?

Comment: Since $\{0,1\}\subset\mathbb Z$, we have that $\{0,1\}^{n\times n}\cap\mathbb Z^{n\times n}$ is simply $\{0,1\}^{n\times n}$, isn't it?

Comment: For the first question, see [OEIS A089482](https://oeis.org/A089482). In fact, this number equals $n!$ times the number DAGs given by [OEIS A003024](https://oeis.org/A003024).

Comment: @MaxAlekseyev If I do not utilize $\mathbb Z$ it would be confusing if I am stating $\mathbb F_2$.

Comment: The intersection is more confusing ($\subset$ would make more sense). Also, $\{0,1\}$ does not mean $\mathbb F_2$ unless you say so.

Comment: @MaxAlekseyev Is there growth asymptotic for OEIS A003024?

Comment: The asymptotic is given in the OEIS.

Comment: Quite interestingly, the answer to the second question for $n=1,2,3,4$ matches the terms of [OEIS A268471](https://oeis.org/A268471). It's immediately unclear if that's just by a coincidence, or if there is some deep connection.

Comment: Interesting I did not expect structure.